# non-linear optimization problem with constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

I have a trouble solving this non-linear optimization... it is difficult for me since it has two sets of variables
$$ \text{i.e. } x_k \text{ and } y_k $$

\begin{align}
f(X,Y)=\max_{x_k, y_k} \sum_{k=1}^L x_k\left(\frac{cy_k}{1+cy_k}\right) 
\\s.t. \sum_{k=1}^L x_k=La, \\
\sum_{k=1}^L y_k=Lb \\
a>0, b>0, c>0, x_k>0 \text{ and } y_k  > 0
\end{align}
and $a, b, c$ are constant value.

I know that 
\begin{align}
f(Y)=\max_{y_k} \sum_{k=1}^L \left(\frac{cy_k}{1+cy_k}\right)
\end{align} is concave function and has maximum when yk has same value i.e. $y_k=b$

here, can we say the function $f(X,Y)$ is

1. concave? and how can I determine $f(X,Y)$ is concave or convex?
2. maximized when $x_k$ and $y_k$ have equal value. i.e. $x_k=a, y_k=b$?

please, help me and I would really appreciate for your help

thanks

Comment: I guess you mean $x_k \geq 0$ and $y_k \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

The keys here are linearity, convexity and monotonicity.

By scaling $x,y,c$ appropriately we can assume that $La = Lb = 1$.

Let $\Sigma = \{x | \sum_k x_k = 1, x_k \ge 0 \}$, $f(y) = {cy \over 1+cy}$. Note that $f$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$.

The problem (I have relaxed the problem slightly) becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
\max_{y , x \in \Sigma} \sum_k x_k f(y_k) &=& \max_{y \in \Sigma} \max_{x \in \Sigma} \sum_k x_k f(y_k) \\
&=& \max_{y \in \Sigma} \max_k f(y_k) \\
&=&  \max_k \max_{y \in \Sigma} f(y_k) \\
&=&  \max_k f(1) \\
&=& f(1) \\
&=& {c \over 1+c}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: is that maximum achieved with equal $x_k ~\ and ~\ y_k $ ? i.e. $x_k=a, y_k=b$??

Comment: @kkimoz: I don't really understand what you are asking. The $\max$ is achieved, for example, with $x=y=(1,0,0,...,0)$.

Comment: my goal is that we can say maximum is achieved when $x_1=x_2=...x_L=a ~\ and ~\  y_1=y_2=...=y_L=b$
however, it isn't from your answer

Comment: @kkimoz: I don't understand why you want that. Why don't you try it on a small example?

Comment: yes, you're right! I could easily verify it.  thank you so much!!!